# Converting a String ArrayList into a Double ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist, double

I'm trying to convert my `String` `ArrayList` into a `Double` `ArrayList` and for some reason it is not converting right.

My input:

```
1 2 3 4
```

My output:

```
[1.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 2.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Expected Output:

```
[1.0] [1.0, 2.0] [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

My Code

```
String inputValue;


List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();



while((inputValue = stdin.readLine()) != null) {

   input.add(inputValue);

    for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        numbers.add (Double.parseDouble(input.get(i)));
    }
    System.out.println(numbers);
}
```

Comment: My input:
1
2
3
4

My output:
[1.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 2.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]

Expected Output:
[1.0]
[1.0, 2.0]
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]

Comment: this comment should be in the qustion itself, so we can see it faster and directly...

Comment: I know but for some reason every time I had it the website thinks its code

Comment: Shouldn't numbers be a list of lists?

Comment: Thank you Ori for editing it

Answer (score 4):

You don't need two loops - you can convert the `String` to `double` when you read the input from `stdin`. Beside that, the output should be printed after the loop in done, once all the numbers are in the lists :

```
    while((inputValue = stdin.readLine()) != null){
       input.add(inputValue);
       numbers.add (Double.parseDouble(inputValue));
    } 
    System.out.println(numbers);
```

Actually, I'm not sure you even need the `input` list.

EDIT :

If you want to print the input as it is added to the Lists, and handle bad input, as well as allow the user to quit the loop by typing enter (i.e. an empty line) :

```
    while((inputValue = stdin.readLine()) != null && !inputValue.isEmpty()) {
       input.add(inputValue);
       try {
           numbers.add (Double.parseDouble(inputValue));
           System.out.println(numbers);
       }
       catch (NumberFormatException numEx) {
           System.out.println(inputValue + " is not a double");
       }
    }
```

Comment: yeah but I need it to print so I know the numbers are going in and even if I enter null or nothing the loops doesn't stop

Comment: @swaguire in that case, you simply need to wrap the `parseDouble` call with a try catch block, to catch NumberFormatException.

Comment: Well is there a way to make it so the while loop stops when null is entered?

Comment: @swaguire I misunderstood your previous comment. Since you are reading the input from stdin (as opposed to reading it from a file), the program will always with for new input when you call readLine(). Therefore, you should choose some String that indicates the end of the input, such as "q", and leave the loop when that String is entered.

Comment: Well for my assignment for this class I need the while loop to stop when null or nothing is entered on the next line. So would I create a string that equals null and then make a parameter saying when something that is equal to that string is entered to stop?

Comment: @swaguire you can compare the input String to an empty String. see edit

Comment: You are a life saver thank you so much and one last thing you wouldn't know how to sort  the arraylist numbers would you?

Comment: @swaguire use `Collections.sort(numbers);`